# Trocar o gif da página

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou criando uma página onde a mesma vai conter um gif que fica em loop, porém gostaria que assim que chegasse ao final do primeiro loop fosse substituído o gif por outro e assim sucessivamente ... da pra fazer isso com javascript ou algo do tipo ? onde encontro a explicação sobre ?

Comment: O loop é da animação do próprio gif ou é um loop de javascript?

Comment: É do próprio gif !

Answer (score 1):

Sabendo o tempo de duração desse loop do primeiro gif, você utiliza um `setTimeout` para trocar por um outro gif. Achei o link abaixo um pouco parecido com a sua pergunta.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171075/how-to-stop-an-animated-gif-from-looping